# Python not recognizing LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: python

I am trying to install Python2.7 on cr-48 chromebook in developer mode, and face a weird issue that I am having hard time searching for a solution on google. First some background.. the root partition is mounted readonly, so I have been installing packages under /usr/local, which is a separate mount point that is writable. There is a way to force root partition itself readwrite (with some minor disadvantages), but I decided not to go that route. I have been downloading archlinux packages and extract them under /usr/local and several of them have been working great so far. I basically extract the `.tar.xz` file somewhat like this:

```
xz -dc package.tar.xz | sudo tar --strip-components=1 -C /usr/local -xvf -
```

This basically drops the files destined for /usr to be under /usr/local instead. I export `/usr/local/lib` ahead of `/usr/lib` under the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and got several packages to work fine this way. For some reason, python fails to load recognize this, though not completely sure what causes it. After expanding python 2.7 package which I got from [archlinux site](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/python2/), I was able to start the python shell fine, and a simple print worked fine. I then tried to install setuptools, so downloaded the source from pypy and tried running `sudo /usr/local/python2 setup.py install`, but it kept giving me the below error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The `libpython2.7.so.1.0` file is in deed there in `/usr/local/lib/` directory which is there in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. A quick run of ldd shows this clearly:

```
chronos@localhost /tmp/setuptools-1.1.6 $ ldd /usr/local/bin/python2
        linux-gate.so.1 (0x777a9000)
        libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0 (0x77610000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x775ee000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x77464000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x77460000)
        libutil.so.1 => /lib/libutil.so.1 (0x7745b000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x77436000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x777aa000)
```

I also checked `/etc/ld.so.conf` and that too has `/usr/local/lib`:

```
chronos@localhost /tmp/setuptools-1.1.6 $ cat /etc/ld.so.conf 
# ld.so.conf autogenerated by env-update; make all changes to
# contents of /etc/env.d directory
/lib
/usr/lib
/usr/local/lib
/usr/lib/opengl/xorg-x11/lib
```

I installed `strace` (and `perl` since it is listed as a dependent), and ran the install command under `strace` which shows the below interesting output (see that it is NOT looking for `/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0` anywhere):

```
chronos@localhost /tmp/setuptools-1.1.6 $ sudo strace /usr/local/bin/python2 setup.py installPassword: 
execve("/usr/local/bin/python2", ["/usr/local/bin/python2", "setup.py", "install"], [/* 16 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x9b3c000
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x776e6000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=37049, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 37049, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x776dc000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/tls/i686/sse2/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/i686/sse2", 0x7fd88d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/i686/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/i686", 0x7fd88d90)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/sse2/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls/sse2", 0x7fd88d90)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/tls", 0x7fd88d90)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/i686/sse2/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/i686/sse2", 0x7fd88d90)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/i686/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/i686", 0x7fd88d90)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/sse2/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib/sse2", 0x7fd88d90)         = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/tls/i686/sse2/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/i686/sse2", 0x7fd88d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/i686/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/i686", 0x7fd88d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/sse2/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls/sse2", 0x7fd88d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7fd88d90)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/i686/sse2/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/i686/sse2", 0x7fd88d90) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/i686/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/i686", 0x7fd88d90)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/sse2/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sse2", 0x7fd88d90)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0
writev(2, [{"/usr/local/bin/python2", 22}, {": ", 2}, {"error while loading shared libra"..., 36}, {": ", 2}, {"libpython2.7.so.1.0", 19}, {": ", 2}, {"cannot open shared object file", 30}, {": ", 2}, {"No such file or directory", 25}, {"\n", 1}], 10/usr/local/bin/python2: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
) = 141
exit_group(127)                         = ?
+++ exited with 127 +++
```

I have always gotten custom installation paths to work by just including the lib path in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and exporting it, so not sure what else I could be missing here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to, somehow, make `setup.py` search all that `libpython*.so*` files prefixed with your `/usr/local/...` path. Use `find` to get existing paths to `libpython2.7.*` and then invoke `setup.py --help` and look for **prefix** options.

Comment: Is the output of **/usr/local/bin/python2 -c 'import os;print(os.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))'** what you expect?

Comment: Yes, returns what is exported.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you probably need to set some Python specific environment variables, like, `PYTHONHOME` & `PYTHONPATH`.  See the [Python man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/python) for the details.

After installing new libraries, you may also need to run `ldconfig` as root to update the library cache file.

Another option to try is to set environment variable `RUN_LD_PATH` or maybe even use `-rpath` or `-rpath-link` compiler/linker options.

You might also try to `prelink` all your executables and libraries under `/usr/local`, although this may be tedious since the directories probably are not listed in `/etc/prelink.conf`.  Maybe just start with your python executable.

Comment: Good guess! I tried setting `export PYTHONHOME=/usr/local/` and `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` but it didn't help :(

Comment: Does 'sudo echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH' output what you expect?

Comment: Yes, it outputs the same value as in the current interactive shell.

Comment: @haridsv  See updated answer for something else to try.

Comment: I can't run ldconfig because the root filesystem is readonly. I guess I will have to recompile on an arch system with `/usr/local` as the prefix and copy the binaries over.

Comment: @haridsv : Maybe try prelinking python, etc.

Comment: Actually, I found that if I switched to root user first using `sudo su -` and then executed python, it would work fine. Looking back, I should have noticed that the issue is with the user environment rather than the installation itself. After all, I was able to start the python shell as the regular user, so it should have found the `.so`, but I somehow failed to pay attention to this detail. To reiterate, `sudo python` was failing, but running python from root shell is working fine, and this gave me a workaround. Thanks for helping me find this workaround.

Comment: Ah, I learned something too then.  So, just so I understand, if the "errant" user did `sudo /usr/local/bin/python2 -c 'import os;print(os.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH"))'`, lots of error messages would have been reported.  Yes?

Comment: Yes, since python won't even start.